# How to allow separate Sonicwall Global VPN clients to reach one another?

Tags: vpn, dell, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

I'm assuming that this should be possible, but I'm not entirely sure. Here's the scenario:

2 offices, both have SonicWALL TZ200s in them, and the two offices are connected together by way of site-to-site VPN tunnel that works beautifully.

But, I have 2 users, one on each of the Sonicwalls, that connects remotely using the SonicWALL Global VPN client, and I want those two machines to be able to reach one another, but they cannot.

All machines in the two offices can reach one another that are on the network and within the site-to-site connection, but the two machines that are using the global vpn clients can only see the machines in the office that they are directly connected to.

I hope that makes sense, please forgive me if not, i'm still pretty new to proper IT & networking lingo.

Thanks in advance, and I will be more than happy to provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You will be going from one NATed network to another, which might have it's own problems.  If it is possible, its likely you will need to add static routes for the subnets the global vpn clients are on to the two SW appliances.  For example, if user1(connects to SW1) is on the virtual network of 10.0.1.0 and user2(connects to SW2) is on the virtual network of 10.0.2.0 then on SW1 you add a route on SW2 for 10.0.1.0 and SW1 for 10.0.2.0.

On SW1
Go to Network > Routing > Add Static Route
Destination Network = the subnet of user2 (10.0.2.0)
Subnet Mask = Likely 255.255.255.0 
Default Gateway = This will be the IP address of the SW2 appliance.

Then do the reverse on SW2.